# Insert html from ajax call in multiple sections

Tags: ajax, html

I make an ajax call to a function which returns html.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(output){
                $("#prikaz_oglasov").html(output);
            } 
            ,error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert('error: ' + status);

            } 
       });
```

I insert the html in a div with a specific id. Now when a onclick event occurs I would like to receive two chunks of html code and insert it in two different divs. I could ofcourse do two ajax calls, but it doesnt seem very efficient. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: so you want to receive 2 different html data or code in just one ajax call??

Answer (score 2):

I think your options are to either make the server return a JSON response looking like

```
{
  chunk1: 'some html',
  chunk2: 'some html'
}
```

and then have something like

```
...
dataType: 'json',
success: function(output){
  $("#prikaz_oglasov").html(output.chunk1);
  $("#prikaz_oglasov2").html(output.chunk2);
} 
...
```

or to try and split the incoming html into two chunks using a regular expression.

Comment: And don't forget to escape `'` in response.

Comment: I am trying to this but I have a problem encoding the codeigniter views(which I use for building the HTML) in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather send 2 separate requests, especially if this HTML is static. Cleaner code is better.